# How I can allow recipient authentication in the Embedded Signing

Tags: docusignapi

In the Embedded Signing there is no recipient authentication in the generated recipient signature URL, Although there is authentication for the recipient in the remote signing.
I am following this sample
https://myapicalls.sampleapps.docusign.com/scenario/2

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different options for [Recipient Auth](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/recipients/auth/).
You can use :

- [code](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/require-access-code-recipient/) (PIN to enter)
- [phone](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/phone-auth/) (text message OR voice call)
- [KBA](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/knowledge-based-authentication/) (Knowledge base, answering questions)
- [IDV](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/id-verification/) (identity verification using government ID)

Each of these have a code example (linked above) that show how to do this with SDKs and in a total of 8 languages.

Comment: There is no way to Authenticate the recipient by using his account's password like the remote signing, also I need to fetch the recipient's signatures that already defined in his account?

Comment: This is done automatically, you don't need to

Comment: If your recipient has a DocuSign account, you can force them to authenticate, but what if they don't? or they don't know their password?

Comment: In my case the recipient must have a Docusign account to sign the document, but the generated signing view still does not ask for the a account's password and also doesn't have the recipient's signatures that are defined. On the other hand, in the remote signing the recipient receives an email with a link for the signing view, once it opened it will ask for the account’s password and then when signing the document the recipient will find their signatures that defined in their account.

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: yes, the signatures will not be found the first time. But you can make it such that it finds them the second time they use your app

Comment: @InbarGazit You mentioned forcing the user to authenticate if they have a DocuSign account - does that work for Embedded Signing?

Comment: yes, it does, did you try it?